# Running HTML file in localhost:8080

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, localhost

I want to run an HTML file in localhost:8080, I'm using the command:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Problem is when I try to open localhost:8080 it downloads the HTML file instead of displaying it.

Comment: Please add more details/code files.

Comment: Without code, we can't really help you, but I think your server might be using a wrong Content-Type that it downloads the HTML instead of displaying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an option that'll put your website on port `8080` because the `http.server` command defaults to port `8000`.

You can do this using:

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

Then when you go to `0.0.0.0:8080` it should show you your webpage instead of a download prompt.

Also, you might have another instance of `http.server` running on port `8080`.

You can find the PID of this task using:

```
ps -A | grep "python3"
```

Which should show something that looks like this:

[image: Command Output]

Then you could kill it using:

```
kill <PID-FOR-PYTHON3-INSTANCE>
```

Or in my case the task that's running on port 8080 is:

```
kill 6856
```

Or, if you don't mind, just kill all Python3 tasks using:

```
killall python3
```

Which in my case would kill both Python3 tasks.

**WARNING:** be very, **VERY** careful before running the `killall` command, because this command ***will NOT save your work***.

**UPDATE:** that blurry section in the picture is my username, I wasn't sure if it would be against the rules to include it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Default port was 8000 , `python3 -m http.server 8080` worked !

Answer (score 3):

> Problem is when I try to open localhost:8080 it downloads the HTML file instead of displaying it.

You want to open http://localhost:8000 instead.

When you use the command you mentioned, `python3 -m http.server`, it defaults to port 8000, as explained in its startup output:

```
$ python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

We don't know what different server you have running on port 8080, but apparently it doesn't put `Content-type: text/html` in its output headers.

## viewing webserver http headers

It's easy to view those headers, e.g. with `wget` use the `-S` switch.